# Hide AJAX call parameter from browser

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, spring, rest

Below is My AJAX code. I want to Hide this AJAX call and its parameters from the browser console. Also the URL should not be called from externally. Here you can find browser screen shot:

[image]

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 var serviceurl="http://192.168.6.81:8085/SpringJSONServicev4/service/"
 var service= serviceurl+"search2/"+FirstName+"/"+PAN ;    
      $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url:service,  
        timeout: 30000,
        cache:false,
        async :true,
     jsonpCallback:'jsonpCallback',
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "jsonp", // "xml", "json"
        success: function(data){
          drawTable(data);
        },  
        error: function(e){  
         /*  alert('Error: ' + e); */  
          alert('Error: ');
        }  
      });  
    }  
</script>
```

Comment: This is not possible, the browser records all traffic and shows it to the user. If you need to stop people making requests directly to your API you need to use a token based authorisation system.

Comment: how to hide those parameters or anything else we can implement

Comment: You can't hide anything. The best thing to do in your case would be to use SSL if you want to encrypt the data being sent.

Comment: without configuring SSL can we hide or before calling can encrypt the data and decry pt at server side

Comment: You could, but it wouldn't be reliable in any way. It depends on the level of security you need.